# Show only English keyboard in EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Good day! I can't figure out how to show the keyboard ONLY in English and with numbers without the ability to change the language for entering in the EditText field.

Is this possible?

Comment: use digit in editText set value a to z and 0 to 9

Comment: @Amitpandey and how does it help me? it will still be possible to switch the language on the keyboard

Comment: yes you will able to switch the langauge but its not write the other langauge in your editText its just take only english alphabet and digit

Answer (score 1):

You should probably filter the input anyways. Forcing English keyboard doesn't force user to use only English letters. User can still long press a character or have a non-english hardware keyboard.

You could listen to text change events and reject all characters that are not accepted by your DB at that point.

though you can solve your problem by

For English Character only:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

With number that's, you can defines in digits string:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789"
```